# detecting blue in image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I was trying to detect blue in image and I got the result as bellow:
why this is happening?
here is the code:

```
import os import numpy as np

img_path = os.path.join("G:\oak","window","1.jpg")

img = cv2.imread(img_path)

resized_img = cv2.resize(img ,(int(img.shape[1]/2),(int(img.shape[0]/2))))

hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(resized_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

print(hsv_image)

low_blue = np.array([94,8,2])

high_blue = np.array([126,255,255])

blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image,low_blue,high_blue)

blue = cv2.bitwise_and(resized_img,hsv_image,mask =blue_mask)

cv2.imshow("window1",resized_img)

cv2.imshow("window",blue)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i want to detect only blue, but as you see in picture some other colors are detected. How can i only detect the blue in image.

Thanks
[image: picture]

Comment: Which one outer or inner?

Comment: i just want that outer blue rectangle

Comment: You need to change low_blue and high_blue depending on ur pc.

Comment: Start a colour-meter/colour-dropper (Digital Color Meter app on macOS) and run it all around your blue frame to see the range of red, green and blues present. Then make a 2x1 pixel image with the lowest RGB as one pixel and the highest as the other. Convert it HSV and use that as the starting point for your `inRange()` parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are using color values for your low and high range coming from the BGR image. Values need to be from the HSV image. Also your bitwise_and command was not correct, if I understand what you wanted.

Here is a correction in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("blue_image.png")

resized_img = cv2.resize(img ,(img.shape[1]//2,img.shape[0]//2))

hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(resized_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

low_blue = np.array([90,215,110])

high_blue = np.array([150,255,190])

blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image,low_blue,high_blue)

blue = cv2.bitwise_and(resized_img,resized_img,mask=blue_mask)

cv2.imwrite("blue_image_processed.png", blue)

cv2.imshow("resized",resized_img)

cv2.imshow("mask",blue_mask)

cv2.imshow("result",blue)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]